# When using React-router, I want to pass location of Link to Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

If I set the Link as follows in a child component:

`` <Link className="article-link" to={`/newsarticle/${title}`}> ``

I want the Route to reflect that in the App.js component:

`` <Route path=`/newsarticle/${title}` component={NewsPage}/> ``

The reason for this is that if the article page gets refreshed in the browser, I want it to render the last `/newsarticle/${title}' that was loaded, rather then to only render '/newsarticle/' without any data from the component passed to newsarticle.

Maybe that can't be done and I need to make sure to do the routing on the server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume you have declared the routes like this

`<Route path="/article/:id" component={Article} />`

and you have defined the link `<Link to="/article/4334">my article</Link>`, where on click of it the route gets loaded, in order to access the parameter which is passed to the route you can try this way

```
/* in Class based component */
class Article extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        console.log(this.props.match.params.id) //where you access the id
    }
    /* rest of the code */
} 


/* in functional Component by using hooks */
  import {useParams} from  'react-router-dom'

  function Article(){
      let params = useParams()
       console.log(params.id)
  }
```

Comment: I don't think I explained the problem is that I am mapping a component "Article" on to the component "Articles" for which I have the route: ```<Route path=`/newsarticle/${title}` component={Articles}/>``` The Link is however in a 3rd Component, which takes us to the relevant article/${title}. What I am trying to achieve is on refresh of the page the URL to remain as article/${title} and the last title shown, thus rendering the content of the last article that was rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I explained the problem is that I am mapping a component "Article" on to the component "Articles" for which I have the route: 
`` <Route path=`/newsarticle/${title}` component={Articles}/> ``

The Link is however in a 3rd Component, which takes us to the relevant article/${title}.

What I am trying to achieve is on refresh of the page the URL to remain as article/${title} and the last title shown, thus rendering the content of the last article that was rendered.